# Why are pending signals cleared on a fork() system call?

Tags: unix, fork

Why is it that pending signals in the parent process do not remain pending in a child process after a `fork()` is executed?

Comment: Because the were meant for the parent? (the child process did not even exist at the moment of sending the signals)

Comment: But, the child receives a copy of the parent's address space on a fork(). Arent pending signals stored somewhere in the parents process address space?

Comment: @VarunRao No, they are metadata in kernel memory.

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/92747/child-process-does-not-inherit-the-pending-signals-from-the-parent-after-a-fork

Comment: Child did is not a *strict* copy of its parent, there are things that are not *inherited* obviously.